# What is the complexity of solving this specific System of Diophantine Equations?

Tags: linear-algebra, number-theory, diophantine-equations, computational-complexity, linear-diophantine-equations

Given a set of linear Diophantine equations such that:

1. There are $3N$ equations.
2. The equations consist of $4N$ unique variables.
3. Each equation is of the form:

- ($a_0$+$a_1$)=($a_2$+$a_3$) or
- ($a_0$+$a_1$)=-($a_2$+$a_3$)
  (where, $a_i$ is a variable)

**Query 1:** What is the computational complexity of solving this system of linear equations (assuming a solution exists).

**Query 2:** Given an additional constraint that: The sum of all 'pairs' in each equation must be a positive integer (i.e. in above examples ($a_0$+$a_1$) and ($a_2$+$a_3$) must be a positive integer). What is the computational complexity of this system of linear equations with the additional constraint (again, we are promised a solution exists).

I could not find any reference related to the above problem or its computational complexity. Can someone please help with this?

Comment: You could just use Gaussian elimination; the system of equations is of the form Mx=0. M is sparse and likely that can be exploited for speed-ups. Also if there are non-trivial solutions then the solutions given by elimination will be rational. Since the equations are homogeneous, they can be made integral too.

Comment: @Aravind Thank you. (Please bear with me as I try to understand): Gaussian Elimination would work fine if the number of variables is same as the number of equations. That part I am clear about. But since here the #Vars=#Equations*(4/3) how can I use Gaussian Elimination? I am not clear how do we quantify 'speed up' here. I am interested about the running time w.r.t. the #Vars or #Equations (in the average case and the worst case)? Secondly there are 2 cases above (second one with additional constraint). I am unclear if you suggested it for both cases or 1 only?

Comment: Elimination works even if the number of variables is larger than the number of equations.   You can try it, for example here: https://www.dcode.fr/gaussian-elimination in the Equation System window. A reference text is Gilbert Strang's book on Linear Algebra. For the second case, what I mean is that if you get a rational solution, say 7/3, 8/4,1/2 for 3 variables, then you can multiply them all by 12 to get an integral solution.

Comment: just to be clear what you are suggesting is: its ALWAYS easy to find a solution in case the variable to equation ratio as well as the form of the problem is as above.(I know we can simplify using Gaussian Elimination but I am talking about a complete solution). Is that a correct interpretation? I understood about the rational part. What I actually meant about the 'second case' is Query 2: Where there is an additional constraint. Is that problem also ALWAYS easy to solve (given the setup as described above)?